# Is there a way to persist state in an iOS Progressive Web App (PWA) that isn't active in the foreground

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, web-push

I've been using iOS's new Web Push support for progressive web apps (PWA). I am running into an issue where any state I store in the service worker (via postMessage from the main thread) gets lost while the PWA is swiped away and not running in the foreground.

My use case is I when I receive the push notification, I want to use some of that state. It seems the service worker running in the background loses context of that state.

I tried working around this via the following methods but it wasn't able to access them properly:

1. Using IndexedDB
2. Using Cache Storage
3. Storing the state value as a class member

I was wondering if anyone has a good way to store state while the PWA app isn't in the foreground with the app off? It seems the service worker becomes active when receiving a 'push' event so I'm hoping there's some way to store something somewhere to use?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to persist state in a web application while the browser is closed or inactive.

1. Cookies. You can simply set a cookie containing the stringified object data. Cookies.js is a standard library for storing, retrieving and manipulating cookies.
2. Localstorage. You can use the localstorage API to directly store data in the user's browser cache. A good library for this is localforage, which is a wrapper for indexed DBs.
3. If you want the data to persist temporarily on the server (especially if you have sensitive information to store) then I suggest using Redis or some form of durable objects at the edge. You can then link those objects to the user via an identifier in a cookie or localstorage.

That said, I also recently began implementing push notifications in mobile Safari. I use a third-party service for this simply because of the complexities involved in implementing this in-house. I would be happy to recommend the vendor I use for this in a DM.

Good luck!